# How do I prevent mobile interface header from overlapping with the content while ensure the content stays below the interface at all times?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

Have been trying to search for a solution so far but to no avail, but basically I had this problem where I'm trying to push my mobile content downwards and make it stick below the mobile interface. This problem persists when I tap on the buttons but the interface anchor keeps overlapping my content header instead of stopping at above the content header itself.

Here's the JS Fiddle for your information: jsfiddle.net/r936zwe1/

I also tried pushing body downwards by inserting padding-top and adjusting the body CSS around but it doesn't seem to work, and the roof of the content keeps stopping at the utmost top side instead of stopping right beneath the mobile interface.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood, correctly, you want to ensure that when a link is clicked within the header and the page animates, that the header does not overlay with the content of the section that it scrolls to.

If that's the case, then simply subtract the height of the header, for instance:

```
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-$('.dock-top').height()
```

You may need to experiment with other offset integers given your current CSS markup, but this should put you in the right direction.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udgLadtz/)

Comment: Oh, it sort of works, thanks. However when I tried on my side, it sort of tried to reach the correct header position but immediately fall back to the previous problem. Do you think I should do something to the above solution you gave? or just the CSS itself will do?

Comment: remove the window.location.hash = target;

Comment: instead you can use history.pushState(null, null, target);